# Please explain working of how are we converting factor variable to numeric in R

Tags: r

Can someone please explain how **as.numeric(levels(x))[x]** exactly work? 
here x is a factor variable.(for example **x<-as.factor(sample(1:5,20,replace=TRUE))** )
As much as i am able to understand is that first we are getting the levels of x (which will be character after that we are changing it to numeric. what is happening after that I am not able to get. I know this representation is same as **as.numeric(as.character(x))**.

Comment: Have you read the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)?

Comment: ...then it's just using `x` values as positions to get the corresponding levels, in a numeric form. You can use `as.numeric(levels(x))[c(1,1,2)]` as an example, which means give me the 1st, 1st (again) and 2nd level. If you try to ask for something that doesn't exist it will return `NA` like this `as.numeric(levels(x))[c(1,1,2,6)]`

Comment: @DeNovo Yes I saw that post but I think It was regarding how to perform the conversion but not about how exactly it is happening.

Comment: @AntoniosK  got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

R factors are vectors of integers that serve as indices into the levels character vector. So the inner part of that expression is creating a character vector. The outer part is converting the set of values: "5", "2", "4" .... etc into numeric values.

```
> x<-as.factor(sample(1:5,20,replace=TRUE))
```

The storage class of factor objects is integer:

```
> dput (x)
structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "factor")
```

The levels() function returns the `.Label` attribute of a factor, and when a factor is used as an index, it gets handled as an integer:

```
> levels(x)[x]
 [1] "4" "2" "3" "4" "5" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "4" "2" "1" "5" "5" "4" "1" "5" "1" "5"
```

This method of conversion or extractions is slightly faster than `as.character(x)`, but as you have experienced, it may seem a bit cryptic if you haven't worked through what is happening "under the hood" (or "bonnet" if that's what it's called in your part of the Englrish speaking world.)

Answer (score 2):

I always confused with R's factors. Usually, I use a perfect idea from **package *Rfast***, the function `Rfast::ufactor`. It represents a factor using its initial type.

Here is an exmple:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
fx<- Rfast::ufactor(x)
fx$levels # you can get the levels like this
fx$values # you can get the values like this
```

Fast and simple. `Rfast::ufactor` is much faster than R's but I will not post any benchmark cause it doens't fit to the question.